# Rebus 2 - Manual retry

Tags: rebus

Is there any 'best practice' for manual retries with rebus2?

I have a custom Web UI for 'error monitoring' and I would like to be able to retry errors manually from Web UI. The problem is that error queue seems to be always 'error' so it doesnt contain the information what is the original queue.

We are using SQL Server as a storage for Rebus messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the headers of the failed message - the [`rbs2-source-queue`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus/Messages/Headers.cs#L47-L50) will be set to the name of the queue in which delivery failed.

The headers are stored in the `headers` column in the messages table as UTF8-encoded JSON - you can inspect it by going

```
SELECT TOP 10 CAST([headers] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM [messages]
```

(which is probably not always 100% correct, since there's no real UTF8 action going on in SQL Server, but it should reveal the headers just fine in most cases)

When you're in C# land, it is easy to do this when you have opened a datareader on the result of a query on the `messages` table:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    var bytesFromHeadersColumn = (byte[])reader["headers"];
    var jsonText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFromHeadersColumn);

    // use a JSON serializer to parse jsonText here...
}
```

which should make it fairly easy to extract the source queue information from the headers of your failed messages.

I hope that makes sense :)